# How do I make all Radio Buttons disabled after n clicks?

Tags: python, tkinter, radio-button

I'm making a quiz-type program, where I've added a bonus question, which is different from the other ones. Here, you're given 8 buttons, and the question is:

> Use four buttons from the given options to pop all elements from the list 'lst'

The buttons are:

```
["lst", "while", "for", "i", ":", "lst.pop()", "in", "range(lst)"]
```

What I want to do, is disable each button after it is clicked, **and** disable all buttons after 4 clicks.

I also wanted to know, how could I check whether the clicks are in the correct order?

I created a function which disables a button with the index 'index'

```py
def disable(buttons, index, word):
    buttons[index].config(state="disabled")
```

Then I created 8 buttons over a loop.

```
words=["lst", "while", "for", "i", ":", "lst.pop()", "in", "range(lst)"]
buttons = []
for index in range(8): 
    n = words[index]
    button = Button(root, text = n, command = lambda index = index, n = n: disable(buttons, index, n)).pack(side = 'left')
    buttons.append(button)
```

This is the error that shows up:

```
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/tkinter/__init__.py", line 1705, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "<ipython-input-163-f56fc3dd64da>", line 340, in <lambda>
    button = Button(root, text = n, command = lambda index = index, n = n: disable(buttons, index, n)).pack(side = 'left')
  File "<ipython-input-163-f56fc3dd64da>", line 353, in disable
    buttons[index].config(state="disabled")
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'config'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change this:

```
for index in range(8):
    n = words[index]
    button = Button(root, text = n, command = lambda index = index, n = n: disable(buttons, index, n)).pack(side = 'left')
    buttons.append(button)
```

To this:

```
for index in range(8): 
    n = words[index]
    button = Button(root, text = n, command = lambda index = index, n = n: disable(buttons, index, n))
    button.pack(side = 'left')
    buttons.append(button)
```

The problem you are seeing is due to using the geometry manager `pack()` on the same line you create the button. As all geometry managers return `None` you will get that error if you try to edit the button.

That said it would probably be better if you wrote the loop like this:

```
# Use import as tk to avoid any chance of overwriting built in methods.
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()
words = ["lst", "while", "for", "i", ":", "lst.pop()", "in", "range(lst)"]
buttons = []

# Use the list to set index.
for ndex, word in enumerate(words):
    # Append the button object to the list directly
    buttons.append(tk.Button(root, text=words[ndex]))
    # Us the lambda to edit the button in the list from the lambda instead of a new function.
    # A useful trick is to use `-1` to reference the last index in a list.
    buttons[-1].config(command=lambda btn=buttons[-1]: btn.config(state="disabled"))
    buttons[-1].pack(side='left')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    root.mainloop()
```

As I believe `index` is a built in method.